# Expression for the work done on a magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, work

In a thermodynamics lecture, I'm required to write down expressions for the work done on a magnetic dipole by a magnetic field.

My lecturer explicitly told me that it is $Bdm$ rather $mdB$, where $B$ is the magnetic field and $m$ is the magnetic dipole moment.

May I ask what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Can you provide some more context on this? From an EM perspective, neither of these expressions properly yield the work done on a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field (given by $\int \tau d\theta$, where $\tau$ is the torque on the dipole given by $\vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}$, where $\vec{\mu}$ is the dipole moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The potential energy of a dipole $\textbf{m}$ in a field $\textbf{B}$ is $U=-\textbf{m} \cdot \textbf{B}$, therefore the work required to change is $\delta W 
 = -dU= d(\textbf{m} \cdot \textbf{B})=\textbf{B} \cdot   d\textbf{m} + \textbf{m} \cdot d\textbf{B}$.

For your question, whether the work done is $\textbf{B} \cdot   d\textbf{m}$ or $\textbf{m} \cdot d\textbf{B}$ depends on what is changing in *your* context, specifically $\textbf{m}$ or $\textbf{B}$ while the *other* variable is kept constant. Of course, if both are changing simultaneously, then the answer to your question is that neither is right for then their sum is the work done.